# JavaScript bind click event to each item in a list after they were added to page dynamically

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I have this code that generate a list of items in my `generator.js` file:

```
var OfferRequest = function( domain ) { 


const List = {

    template: null,
    orItems: [],

    SetData( data ) {

        if (data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
        return this;
    },

    GenerateItems() {
        if (!this.data || !this.data.length) {
            
            Loader.RecordsLoaded( 'Nu au fost inregistrate formulare.' );

        } 
        else {

            this.template = Template.Get('List','orItemTemplate').html();

            Template.Get('List','orListContainer').empty();

            let delay = 0;

            $(this.data).each((k, r) => {
                    
                let tpl = this.template.replace('', ''); // trick to get a copy of the template

                $.each(r, (i, v) => {
                    tpl = tpl.replace(`[${i}]`, v);
                });

                setTimeout(() => {

                    Template.Get('List','orListContainer').append( tpl );       
                    Settings.Store.Add( r );
                
                }, delay+=25);

            });
        }

    },


    Append( data ) {
    // ...
    }


}




async function Init( data, prospect ) {
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        if (!prospect) reject('Invalid param [prospect]');

        List.SetData( data ).GenerateItems();
        Settings.ProspectId = prospect;

        resolve();

    });
}



return {
    Init,
    Loader,
    Add,
    OpenRequest,
    GetExpander: () => Expander,
    ContractValability: Settings.Contract.Valability,
    OpenInfo,
    SetUnFinished,
    UpdateOffersCount,
    Offers
}
```

}

and somewhere on a page that includes this file, i have this code for initialize and bind events:

```
let OR = new OfferRequest( 'ee' );

OR.Init( response, postData.prospect ).then(() => {

    PLUGIN.applyButtonAction({ target: 'div.or-item', fn: OR.OpenRequest }); // this is called before the items have rendered to page

}).catch(error => Dash.Server.Error( error ));
```

the problem is that on `OR.Init()`, the `Promise` is resolved before `List.GenerateItems()` to be done.
the `List.GenerateItems` has a setTimeout inside, and I dont have any Ideea how to force the `async Init()` to wait for all process inside to be finished before it resolve the `Promise`

Is there a way to use `async`, `await`, and `promise` to achive this?

Comment: sounds like you should call that code after you add the items....

Comment: Make `GenerateItems retuns promise` then resolve that promise when every operation is completed. And in Init function call as `await List.SetData( data ).GenerateItems();`

Comment: adding `await List.SetData( data ).GenerateItems();` in `Init` throws an `Uncaught ReferenceError: OfferRequest is not defined` - i have tried this before..

Comment: maybe an `async` should be used somewhere